# Remove specific sentences from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string of below format : (Sentences with 3 or more spaces and sentences between such sentences are part of table data)

```
Some Sentence
Some sentence


Balance at January 1,                                $421            $51
Additions based on tax positions related to the

current year                                                    4        34         9

Additions based on acquisitions                           -       -       2
Additions based on tax positions related to prior

years                                                    21       13     374
Reductions for tax positions of prior years                (54)     (43)      -

Some paragraph
Some paragraph

Balance at January 1,                                $421            $51
Additions based on tax positions related to the

current year                                                    4        34         9

Additions based on acquisitions                           -       -       2
Additions based on tax positions related to prior

years                                                    21       13     374
Reductions for tax positions of prior years                (54)     (43)      -
```

I need to remove all the sentences from the string which contains 3 or more spaces keeping in mind that the actual paragraph contents should be maintained.

Below is my approach which does not give me accurate result and I am also not happy using range(5):

```
for i in range(5):
result = re.sub('[\\n-].* {3,}.*\\n', '', result)
print(result)
```

**Output of my logic :**

```
Some Sentence
Some sentence


Additions based on tax positions related to the
Additions based on tax positions related to prior



Some paragraph
Some paragraph

Additions based on tax positions related to the
Additions based on tax positions related to prior
```

**Expected Output :**

```
Some Sentence
Some sentence


Some paragraph
Some paragraph
```

What more can be done so sentences between sentences(having 3 or more spaces) are also removed?

Answer (score 2):

```
sentences = """
Some Sentence
Some sentence


Additions based on tax positions related to the
Additions based on tax positions related to prior



Some paragraph
Some paragraph

Additions based on tax positions related to the
Additions based on tax positions related to prior
"""

splitted_sentences = sentences.split('\n')

only_short_sentences = [line for line in splitted_sentences if len(line.split()) <3]
short_sentences_str = '\n'.join(only_short_sentences)
print(short_sentences_str)
```

output:

```
Some Sentence
Some sentence





Some paragraph
Some paragraph
```

if you want to discard empty lines - convert to this version of list comprehension:

```
only_short_sentences = [line for line in splitted_sentences if len(line.split()) <3 and line]
```

is that the expected result?

### edited

input:

```
sentences = """
Some Sentence
Some sentence


Balance at January 1,                                $421            $51
Additions based on tax positions related to the

current year                                                    4        34         9

Additions based on acquisitions                           -       -       2
Additions based on tax positions related to prior

years                                                    21       13     374
Reductions for tax positions of prior years                (54)     (43)      -

Some paragraph
Some paragraph

Balance at January 1,                                $421            $51
Additions based on tax positions related to the

current year                                                    4        34         9

Additions based on acquisitions                           -       -       2
Additions based on tax positions related to prior

years                                                    21       13     374
Reductions for tax positions of prior years                (54)     (43)      -
"""
```

output:

```
Some Sentence
Some sentence






Some paragraph
Some paragraph
```

Comment: No @Yossi Levi, Please refer expected result in the question. The line feeds should also be maintained in the output.

Comment: fixed this part. now as expected? editd to version that maintain empty lines, and a version that discard them.

Comment: Tried the solution after replacing "Some sentence" with actual sentence and "Some paragraph" with actual paragraph and that did not work.

Comment: I edited the answer so that you will see the output for real sentences. Took the example that you provided at your post and tried on it. work perfect, pay attention that all the other sentences have more than 3 words (more precisely, they have more than 2 whitespaces)

Comment: Hi @Yossi Levi, I agree your code works for given input but can you try using string from here : https://regex101.com/r/hOrp78/1

Comment: `-F-23-----DECEMBER 31,-- ------------2018 2017--$409--2016-- -------- `, conerted each newline to `-` to make it clearer - it looks fine. only short sentences survived. You can ask me privately if you still confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221699/discussion-between-crusader-and-yossi-levi).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy regular expression for this (I've put your input into file "test.txt"):

```
grep -v " .* .* " test.txt
```

As you see, it's just three times a space with in between `".*"`, which stands for "every possible character, repeated an unknown number of times (might be zero)".
Oh, before I forget: the `"-v"` stands for "things **not** to see in the results".

Apparently you know about the `re` Python library, so you might know how to embed this regular expression into your Python source code.

Good luck

Comment: Hi @Dominique, I know alternative to grep in python is re.findall but I do not know how to incorporate -v from the answer. Can you help?